# Error comparing strings in Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, string, cocos2d-x, strcmp

I am using cocos2d-x to create an Android game.

I am calling a static function within a different class that checks if a given username and password is correct. The function returns a string, "yes" if both username and password are correct, "no" otherwise.

I then compare the string to decide what to do next. The problem I am having is that in CCLOG it prints response is "yes", however the if branch does not execute, i.e. strcmp(result.c_str(), "yes") does not return true but CCLOG prints result to be "yes".

Here is my code :

```
// LogInPage
if (((CCMenuItemSprite*) pSender)->getTag() == 0) {
    string username = string(m_pEditUsername->getText());
    string password = string(m_pEditPassword->getText());

    string result = SQLDatabase::logIn(username, password);
    CCLOG("RESULT IS %s", result.c_str());

    if (strcmp(result.c_str(), "yes") == 0) {
        CCLOG("IN IF BRANCH");
        CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(PlayMultiplayerPage::scene());
    }
}
```

// STATIC LOGIN FUNCTION

```
string SQLDatabase::logIn(string username, string password) {
    stringstream strm;
    strm << "http://****.net/select_functions.php?
function=logIn&username="
        << username << "&password=" << password;

CURL* curl;
CURLcode res;
string result;
curl = curl_easy_init();
string URL = strm.str();

if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Write_To_String);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &result);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    CCLOG("curl return code is %i", (int) res);
    CCLOG("response is \n %s", result.c_str());
}

return result;
}
```

// WRITE_TO_STRING FUNCTION

```
size_t SQLDatabase::Write_To_String(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count,
        void *stream) {
    ((string*) stream)->append((char*) ptr, 0, size * count);
    return size * count;
}
```

Comment: There must be some unwanted characters in the `result` string. Check it's length and the individual characters in it. It might still look ok when printed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use c++ specific function for that.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

If that doesn't work

```
 char * cstr = new char [str.length()+1];
 std::strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());
```

and then compare it.

Comment: i tried the compare function before too, that still didnt work. The method you gave also doesnt work.